# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting, 'python2.7-dev' is missing final newline, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

After running

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

I am getting following error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:  
files list file for package 'python2.7-dev' is missing final newline.  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

If I run:

```
sudo apt install python2.7-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
python2.7-dev is already the newest version (2.7.15~rc1-1ubuntu0.1).
```

If I try to remove any other package, I face the same error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:  
files list file for package 'python2.7-dev' is missing final newline  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: would you be open to first removing python 2.7 then installing it anew after having upgraded? if so : `sudo apt purge python2.7 -y && sudo apt autoclean -y && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt install python 2.7 -y` do you even use python 2.7? like do you code in it? if no you don't need it, modern ubuntu apps are in python 3

Comment: @tatsu, `sudo apt purge python2.7 -y` is also not working and giving similar error.

Comment: ok try this : `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst.bak && sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.list.back && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` how about now? (first try to figure out what what files you have by pressing double-tab with `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7` if you have `python2.7-dev.postrm`, `python2.7-dev.postinst` and  `python2.7-dev.list` rename those (like i did) first.

Comment: which one? `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst.bak` or `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-dev.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-dev.postinst.bak`? I'm going to add an answer. please mark it as a way to help others with the same problem as you.

Comment: @tatsu I renamed all the files in that directory as you told and then followed the other commands as mentioned.

Comment: great! please mark the answer and feel free to upvote! glad I could help out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing the following into a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) should solve your issue :

(rename all the "python2.7" files you find under `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` like so : (look for the others I only showed how to rename the ones that would obviously be there))

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst.bak &&
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.list.bak &&
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.postinst /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-dev.postinst.bak &&
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7.list /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7-dev.list.bak &&
sudo dpkg --configure -a &&
sudo apt clean &&
sudo apt autoremove && 
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

if this works you may delete the files you renamed :

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python2.7*.bak`